# Inserting value to std::set without an intermediate variable

Tags: c++

From the cpp [set example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/) we can do a set assignment using the following:

```
  std::set<int> myset;
  std::set<int>::iterator it;
  std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator,bool> ret;

  // set some initial values:
  for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i) myset.insert(i*10);    // set: 10 20 30 40 50

  ret = myset.insert(20);               // no new element inserted

  if (ret.second==false) it=ret.first;  // "it" now points to element 20

  myset.insert (it,25);                 // max efficiency inserting
  myset.insert (it,24);                 // max efficiency inserting
  myset.insert (it,26);                 // no max efficiency inserting
```

However, I need to have the following pair:

```
std::pair<std::set<int>,bool[5]> ret;
```

The first type should be flexible and the second type will be fixed for each *first*.

My aim is to have such thing:

```
item[0][0] = false
item[0][1] = false;
item[2][2] = true; etc.
```

Can someone give me a small example on how to create such structure?

Comment: `std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator,bool>` is the return type of the `insert()` overload you are using. You can't change that to `std::pair<std::set<int>,bool[5]>` if that is the intention.

Comment: @MariusBancila no. It was just to make it clear how I want it

Comment: `std::map<int, bool[5]>` would allow that kind of access you describe. Not sure if it helps you though ... not quite the same thing

Comment: This question is incomprehensible.  It would seem `std::pair<std::set<int>,bool[5]> ret;` might express the result of 5 insertion attempts, some of which might fail as duplicates - fair enough.  "The first type should be flexible..." - `ret.first` is *dynamically sized*, is that what you mean?  But "and the second type will be fixed for each *first*."? Are you noting the array dimensions fixed? But I can't make sense of "for each *first*" if so.  And `item[a][b] = true`/`false;` - where did `item` come from? How on earth does that relate to the set populated above?

Comment: @TonyD Yes, the first type is flexible as you also mentioned (dynamically sized). The second is also fixed if we can use the arrays as I indicated in the example (`bool[5]`). `item` here is just a dummy name which could be replaced by `myset` which I will update now.

Comment: If `item` is better named `myset` - implying it is the returned set - then `item[a][b] = ...` is not a meaningful statement... `item[a]` in the set accesses an `int`... you can't index that `int` with `[b]`, let alone assign `true`/`false` afterwards.  And, what's all this got to do with efficiency of insertion, or is that mentioned for not reason?  And in "without an intermediate variable" what variable in your code are you talking about?